# What is the most common, industry preferred /used payload formatting method?

Tags: mqtt, payload

I'm pretty new to *IOT/MQTT* and for my internship i was given a project to parse some *MQTT* data and display it in a Unity 3D application. The *POC* is done but it works only with *JSON* for now.

I read this **[article](https://modelbasedtesting.co.uk/2015/12/06/why-doesnt-mqtt-have-a-payload-format/)** and is well explained by the creators that the payload is completely undefined.
I read about some options **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084628/which-is-the-most-lightweight-and-efficient-message-payload-format-to-exchange-o/63088705#63088705)** too, but I'm not yet totally sure yet exactly what it is.

So my questions are :

- Is there any other payload format that i should focus / worry about?
- Is Json the most used one? If not, what should i expect?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084628/which-is-the-most-lightweight-and-efficient-message-payload-format-to-exchange-o

Answer (score 0):

99% of the IoT work I do with MQTT is done in JSON.....the other 1% is unformatted binary data.  Some of my customers want the data in XML format because that is what their systems use and/or their developers are comfortable with....but that is getting more and more rare as languages like Node.js and GO seem to work better with JSON than XML -- but that is just my opinion. Both support XML just fine.